In a thermochemistry question, why does formation of water equation ask for a specific balancing?
I was solving a medium level question in thermochemistry which involved combustion and formation enthalpies. But when I it solved by myself, I found out that my answer differed from the one in the book (NCERT), but both solutions had a minor and a rather puzzling difference, and couldn't find a reasonable answer to it.
Here's the question-
The combustion of one mole of benzene
takes place at 298 K and 1 atm. After combustion, CO2 (g) and H2O (1) are produced and 3267.0 kJ of heat is liberated. Calculate the standard enthalpy of formation, ∆H (formation) of benzene. Standard enthalpies of formation of CO2 (g) and H2O(l) are –393.5 kJ /mol and – 285.8 kJ /mol respectively.


Here, in the solution taken from the ncert book itself, the water formation equation has coefficients 1: 1/2 :1 for respective molecules.
Why can't we take a simple whole number ratio for the coefficients 2:1:2.
Why does it go wrong? This is confusing me.
Thank you for your time.

It is not a good idea to use images as part of a question.

More precisely, text in image should be written down, using Mathjax for equations.

Oh I apologize, I am new to the community.

When you double the coeeficients ,there is doubled the reaction enthalpy. The standard enthalpy of liquid water formation is equal to reaction enthalpy where 1 mol ( = coefficient 1) of water is produced. // NCERT calculation is too complicated. Standard reaction enthalpy is the difference of sums of (product formation enthalpy multiplied by stoich. coefficient) and (reactant formation enthalpy multiplied by stoich. coefficient).

If you consider simple stoic, Coeff like 2:1:2 You will be calculating the Enthalpy of formation of water for only 2 moles of Water.
But In Benzene we have a net total of 6 Moles of Hydrogen Atoms
If you take 2:1:2 ratio of formation of water:
2 H2 + O2 $\overset{\rightarrow}\dashrightarrow$ 2H2O
The Total H Atoms in this reaction is 4
However we need 6 H atoms
So,
3H2 + 1.5 O2 $\overset{\rightarrow}\dashrightarrow$ 3H2O
here we have net total of 6 H Atoms Which is sufficient for formation of benzene which literally has 6 H atoms in its molecule

By taking stociometric coefficients in ratio 2:1:2 we are calculating enthalpy of formation of 2 moles of H2O (as you can see in equation of 2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O). You can use the ratio as 2:1:2 but for calculating the answer to the question you have to take care of no of H2O used. In this case you have to multiply it by (1.5).
